# How can I parse std out in python?

Tags: python, stdout, python-3.7

I have the output below. I want to get only IP Address line. I wrote a for loop for it but it doesnt work.

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : 
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
IPAddress        : {192.168.1.156, fe80::801:8189:f074:bcda}
PSComputerName   :
```

Here is my code:

```
sonuc = session.run_ps('Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where ipEnabled=TRUE"') 
for line in sonuc.std_out:
        if "IPAddress" in line:
            print(line)
```

How can I reach the IP Address line?

Comment: how did you get that output in the first place and what is `sonuc.std_out`?

Comment: sonuc = session.run_ps('Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where ipEnabled=TRUE"') it is the first part of my code. I got sonuc from there

Comment: for getting the output I wrote sonuc.std_out

Comment: that should be included in the question not comments

Comment: And `sonuc.std_out` is a function or the output?

Comment: sonuc.std_out is an output

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```py
import sys
import io

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = buffer = io.StringIO()

print("""__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : 
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
IPAddress        : {192.168.1.156, fe80::801:8189:f074:bcda}
PSComputerName   : """)

sys.stdout = old_stdout

printed = buffer.getvalue()

for line in printed.splitlines():
    if 'IPAddress' in line:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
IPAddress        : {192.168.1.156, fe80::801:8189:f074:bcda}
```

(nothing else is printed)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without writing print("""__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
__SUPERCLASS  ....... etc )

Comment: Replace the `print(...)` with the code that prints `__GENUS : ...`. I didn't have that code so I had to use a print statement

Comment: __GENUS ---> ı got this with writing sonuc=result2.std_out. In the code when i replace print(sonuc) i got the same output with stripting \\ like b'\r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration\r\n__SUPERCLASS ......